# Deployed Sails App on Elastic Beanstalk not loading static files

Tags: amazon-web-services, sails.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have my sailsjs app to serve the static files from a custom directory so my .sailsrc file looks like

```
{"hooks": { "grunt": false},
 "paths": {
   "public": "public"
  }
 }
```

This works fine locally but when the app is running on Elastic Beanstalk it won't serve the files from the public directory they all return a 404 error. I've ssh to my instance to confirm all the files have been uploaded correctly and they are, so I'm bit lost as to why it's not working as the rest of the app works fine.

Answer (score 0):

OK seems just adding the .sailrc so added to customMiddleware

```
customMiddleware: function(app) {
 var express = require('sails/node_modules/express');
 app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));
}
```